# Adding items from a while loop to an ArrayList java

Tags: java, list, collections, properties, arraylist

Simple one here, I have connected to a sqldb and from my database
I am retrieving rows from a table.

For each row i wish to save the data to an `ArrayList`. Each row being an
item in the `ArrayList`.

This is what I have so far.

```
List<DVDProperty> DVDList = new ArrayList<DVDProperty>();

DVDProperty context = new DVDProperty();

while (res.next()) {
    int i = res.getInt("idnew_table");
    String s = res.getString("dvdName");

    context.setDVDId(i);
    context.setDVDName(s);

    DVDList.add(context);
}
```

`DVDPropery` is a set property where i set the properties with the table row values.

I have 2 rows with the following data

1 Scarface
2 Avatar

Everytime I Run through the loop my `ArrayList` overrides 
1 Scarface 
with 2 Avatar twice

I wish to add a new row to my `ArrayList` each time
and it not override

Answer (score 12):

Instantiate `DVDProperty` inside the loop. Currently you are reusing the same instance, and thus overriding its properties:

```
while (res.next()) {
   DVDProperty context = new DVDProperty();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to create new object of type DVDProperty for every record. At this time you change the same object (context) in every iteration. Try:

```
List<DVDProperty> DVDList = new ArrayList<DVDProperty>();
while (res.next()) {
    int i = res.getInt("idnew_table");
    String s = res.getString("dvdName");
    DVDProperty context = new DVDProperty();
    context.setDVDId(i);
    context.setDVDName(s);
    DVDList.add(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please create new instance of the DVDProperty object in loop everytime it runs the loop.
Please refer to code snippet below.

Code
List<DVDProperty> DVDList = new ArrayList<DVDProperty>();
DVDProperty context = null;
while (res.next()) {
    int i = res.getInt("idnew_table");
    String s = res.getString("dvdName");
    context = new DVDProperty();
    context.setDVDId(i);
    context.setDVDName(s);
    DVDList.add(context);
}
```